# Stripe-Android SDK doesn’t comply with the User Data and Mobile Unwanted Software policies of Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, stripe-payments, google-play-services, privacy-policy

Yesterday my app was removed from Google Playstore because it was using the Stripe-Android SDK.

Here is the reason why my app was removed from Google Playstore :

> We’ve identified that your app is using Stripe SDK or library, which
> facilitates the transmission and collection of Phone Number and
> Installed Application information without meeting the prominent
> disclosure guidelines. Make sure to also post a privacy policy in both
> the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the
> Play distributed app itself. If necessary, you can consult your SDK
> provider(s) for further information.

As on my side I do not collect any information of any kind, how could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally managed to solve the problem. What you have to do is:

1. Update the Stripe SDK
2. Upload your app update to **all release tracks** (production, open,
   closed and internal), incrementing the version number each time. Right after uploading the APK file and before resubmitting your app for review, please make sure to **deactivate the non-compliant APK (*)**.
3. Go to the **Publishing overview** page and click **Send for review** to submit your changes. (This is important. I had missed this point)

Maybe Google will ask you to add a privacy policy too. You will have to:

1. Post a privacy policy explaining very precisely how you collect data and what you do with it. (even if you do not collect any data)
2. On the play console page, go to App Content -> Privacy policy and enter the URL of your privacy policy.
3. **Inside your app**, put a link to your privacy policy. (I missed that point too)

Less than 24 hours later, my app became accessible again on Play Store.

**Good to know 1** : If you've done all of these steps and your app is still offline, you can contact the Google policy support team at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/emailappeals

**(*) Good to know 2** : Here is where you can deactivate the non-compliant Bundle:
[image]

Comment: can you provide the stripe v you updated to?

Comment: com.stripe:stripe-android:17.1.2

Comment: I am using this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/stripe_payment (v1.1.4). I tried all these steps, still no luck. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: we have follow above all steps , Still no luck , Using this plugin : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe (v1.3.0) can you help about above policy issue?

Comment: Right after uploading the APK file and before resubmitting your app for review, please make sure to deactivate the non-compliant APK. (Uncheck the checkbox at the bottom of the page)

Comment: Yes ,  There was old version bundle deactivated and latest bundle activated.
Today rejected after uploaded latest bundle in all track with 100% rollout.

Comment: If you've done all of these steps and your app is still offline, you can contact the Google policy support team at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/emailappeals

Comment: are you sure ?, it working fine latest stripe sdk version 17.1.2 with google policy? now your app live with stipe sdk 17.1.2?

Comment: Yes it is. The problem must come from your privacy policy. Find an app which works with Stripe and check its privacy policy.

Comment: @Denis Hi Denis/everyone else. Do you know any app that works with Stripe so we can check the privacy policy? Could you share yours with us please?

Comment: @Denis, Can you please share your app's privacy policy with us? Its been more than 2 weeks since my app was rejected. Desperately looking for solutions!! Submitted multiple appeals (Always receive an error on my email that APK link is not accessible) and contacted them via chat, they said they cannot respond to privacy policy related issues over chat. then I emailed them but no response.

Comment: @YawarYounus any update I have the same problem and I cannot solve it

Comment: @Denis There is no option to deactivate the non-compliant APK if you use app bundles

Comment: @ArmandoMendivil I couldn't fix it yet. If you or anybody else finds a solution please post it here

Comment: Here is how to deactivate the non-compliant APK : https://newbedev.com/how-to-deactivate-my-previous-version-retained-apk-in-play-store

Comment: @Denis Check the updated answer in the link you posted : 
.
.
Simple answer for this is "Now you can't". With App Bundles it deactivates your previous release versions at the time of new version release.

Comment: @YawarYounus Of course you can. Please have a look at the screenshot.

Comment: @YawarYounus I could solve it updating the Information Collection and Use in y privacy policy, I used this generator https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/ I used facebook, one signal and Google Play Services, the generator does not have stripe after generate the information collection and use I added manually the stripe link, I created a internal version and production version and thats it rn my app is available on play store again

Comment: HI, @ArmandoMendivil can you please share the Stripe Link?

Comment: @MithuRoy I'm using this one https://stripe.com/privacy I added the link inside of  collection and Use section of my privacy policy

Comment: @ArmandoMendivil thanks for sharing. Please, specify what version of stripe plugin you had? Have you used flutter plugin? thanks

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв im using react native with this library @stripe/stripe-react-native v0.2.2

Comment: @Denis Even after updating the stripe SDK to 17.0.0 in my android project ,I am getting the same prominant disclosure and privacy policy issue. Please suggest how to fix.

Comment: @YawarYounus did u manage to fix the issue?

Comment: @ymerdrengene I uploaded new app and it was approved immediately. Until now it's live without any problems. Apparently once they reject your app they block it or they check it more strictly

Answer (score 0):

In my case,

1. I forgot to follow the installation instructions from [Stripe SDK](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe)

[image]

2. I added the following clause in my privacy policy:

"MY_APP uses stripe payments. which requires information about your phone number and apps installed on the device in order to ensure secure and successful payment."

and it worked ✨

Comment: Hi @M.AQIB three questions. 
1) Where is your privacy policy? In a webpage?
2) Is the clause only in your privacy policy or it is also in the App itself? 
3) Do you have a link for the privacy policy? How the users accept it? With a checkbox or something?

Comment: I have my privacy policy on the web and in the application too. https://youfeedapp.com/privacypolicy

yes, the user accepts it while signing up using a checkbox!